# WinRT C# - out of memory - reading image files

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, bitmapimage

I have a fairly simple program that tries to read all the graphic files in my Picture Library.  I create a bitmapImage for each file and I never use it or reference it.  After reading 61 files, I get an Out of Memory exception - it is reproducible, it always dies on the 61st file.

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream =
      await pic.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
      await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
```

The above code snippet shows the gist of what I am doing.  I create a bitmapImage in a method, return it to the caller and never keep it or reference it.

Given that I have kept no references to the bitmapImages, shouldn't GC collect the unreferenced bitmapImages?

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Frank

-----  here is the expanded code ------

```
    private IEnumerator<StorageFile> hdEnum = null;

    /*
     * Initialize to read all the pic files in the PicturesLibary.
     * 
     */

    private async Task initializeEnum()
    {
        if (hdEnum != null)
        {
            // I have already been initialised so go away
            return;
        }

        folder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;

        // Set query options with filter and sort order for results
        List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".gif");
        var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, fileTypeFilter);

        // Create query and retrieve files
        var query = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);

        // Query the folder.
        var fileList = await query.GetFilesAsync();
        hdEnum = fileList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    /*
     * Read and return the next picture file in the PicturesLibrary
     */

    public async Task<BitmapImage> next()
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(); ;

        StorageFile pic = null;

        if (hdEnum == null)
        {
            await initializeEnum();
        }

        if (hdEnum.MoveNext())
        {
            pic = hdEnum.Current;   // hdEnum is an enumerator on the list of image files
        }           

        if (pic != null)
        {
            // come here if I have an image to read
            String path = pic.Path;


            Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream =
            await pic.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
            fileStream.Dispose();

            // force a GC - this makes no difference, it still dies after the 61st file
            GC.Collect();
            Debug.WriteLine("Read: " + ++fileCount + " " + pic.Path + " " + GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
        }

         bitmapImage = null;  // EXPLICITLY MAKING IT NULL - no references
        return (bitmapImage);
    }
```

Comment: after you get the IRandomAccessStream object, how do you use that object? Can you show the related code?

Comment: I added the relevant bits of code to my original message.  As it shows, I dispose of the filestream and I return a bitmapImage but it is never referenced by the caller.

Comment: one other bit of info: if I comment out the line "await bitmaImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);"  then everything works without a hitch.